How to properly pass spark session with hive configuration to a function in pyspark?
I tried running a script like this:

def main():
    # Initialize Spark Session with Hive support
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("Read Hive Data") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///usr/local/hive/warehouse") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

    # Read the table
    table_df = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM default.XYZ')
    table_df.show()


and it all works fine, it seems the configuration works.
But when I create a separate function in a separate script:

def func1(spark: SparkSession) -> None:
  
    # Read the table
    table_df = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM default.XYZ')
    table_df.show()


In main then I do:
from script import func1

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("Read Hive Data") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///usr/local/hive/warehouse") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

    func1(spark)


And surprisingly, I get:
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view XYZ cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.

I verified that I operate on the same venv, in the same project, I don't understand why spark would find the table without a problem in one script, and not see it in another.
Thanks
